# spl_autoload_register() with subfolders structure matching namespaces

Tags: php, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I've dicided to rewrite autoloader that currently exists in project, to replace an old __autoload() with spl_autoload_register(). While searching for an optimal solution, I've found this most upvoted commentary on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514), that states:

> Good news for PHP 5.3 users with namespaced classes:
>
> When you create a subfolder structure matching the namespaces of the
> containing classes, you will never even have to define an autoloader.

So basic realization is simple:

```
class Autoloader
{
    function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
        spl_autoload_register();
    }
}
```

And adding subfolders with same namespaces allows to minimize amount of boot operations to this:

```
require('bone/classes/autoloader.php');
$autoloader = new bone\classes\Autoloader;

#Start working with classes...
$custom_class = new meat\classes\Custom_class;
```

While this looks small and fast, the question is:

**Is there any huge problems this solution could lead to in future? Because, for example, Zend/Symphony loaders are much more complex, and I believe for a good reason.**

(For example, adding a "vendor" prefix to namespaces - according to PSR-0 - could be a bit of a problem, because it should match directory as well - a webroot directory)

Hoping to receive any constructive point of view. Thank you.

Comment: You can always extend your autoloader at any time for some features. Symfony uses Composer afaik. Composer is a lot more complex because it's a dependency manager not just an autoloader. I used to have my own autoloader too but know I switched to composer which makes a lot of things a lot easier.

Comment: So, the question is a bit broad. If there's a *specific* problem you're worried about, ask that. If you're running into a *specific* error, ask that. Asking if there is *any* problem... well, sure. There's a lot of possibilities in the world.

Comment: Anything is possible, right, but this could end up being the root of all evil, and more experienced developers could easily notice what I can not.

Comment: I would adivce you to try out composer. You can think about it what you wan't. Some say it's a security risct, some say it's pretty awesome. I used to tell everyone for a long time that composer is a security risk cause uf manipulated packages. In fact you don't have to use dependencies in your project at all but just autoload your own stuff with composer and you're ready to use dependencies in future if you ready to do it.